# Windows Run Schedule Highest Permissions acces blocked

Tags: windows-10, batch, uac

I am making a batch file that will create a task in Run Schedule that runs Taskmanager when pc startups with UAC Permissions.
I made this code

```
/Create /TN Taskmanager /SC ONLOGON /TR C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe /F /RL HIGHEST
```

But when I execute it, it will say acces denied...
How can I fix this because I want it to run as UAC and no prompt because the promt anyoing when you start your pc.

Thank you!

Comment: The command you are trying to use will always generate an UAC prompt in order to elevate the permissions of taskmgr.exe to that of an Administrator.  By default a process has the lowest permission possible even when launched by a Administrator.

Comment: And how do I prevent UAC prompt on a file when Logon?

Comment: You can't due, your command is attempting to elevate the permissions on taskmgr.exe, there is no way to supress the UAC prompt if you have UAC set to the default settings

Comment: and what if i use it for a other file on desktop?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: If I move a exe file on Desktop and do /Create /TN Text /SC ONLOGON /TR c:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\SuperUser.exe /F /RL HIGHEST
It still says No Acces

Comment: Your still elevating the permissions on the executable.

Comment: So its not possible to auto OK the UAC Prompt?

Comment: No; It is not possible to automatically confirm the UAC prompt.

Comment: Its it possible to auto accept UAC on all files ;-;? (Sorry for being anoying)

Comment: activate the checkbox "Run with highest privileges" in task scheduler when  you create the task

Comment: An UAC prompt can only be confirmed by the actual user.

Comment: @Ramhound there is a workaround since Vista available to workarond the prompt ;) http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472

Comment: @magicandre1981 - The author specifically requires running the program with Administrator permissions, or that's my perception of the question, and "Run with highest priviligies" simply runs the process with the user's highest possible permission.  Its not clear if the user profile the author is starting the process with is an Administrator or not.